# Setting up cross browser functionality in webdriverio

Tags: typescript, webdriver-io

My team is building automation framework in webdriverio from scratch. How to setup functionality to run scripts in Chrome, Edge and Firefox?

I am unable to find a definite solution. I am using v7 for wdio.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use Selenium grid

(or)

2. You can specify it as the capabilities which is available in the `wdio.conf.js`. For this you need [wdio-chromedriver-service](https://webdriver.io/docs/wdio-chromedriver-service) and [wdio/firefox-profile-service](https://webdriver.io/docs/firefox-profile-service)installed

```
  capabilities: [
    {
      browserName: 'chrome',
    },
    {
      browserName: 'firefox',
    },
  ],
```